# xml trans to html with xslt ,but I can't get the value of "version"

Tags: xslt

[Unable to get the value, and I can't find the namespace file for help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Oac.png)

Comment: You should not include code samples as images. Please edit your question to include the code samples as text. To format code to be readable, just highlight the textblock, and then click the `{}` button to format it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:an="http://checklist.nist.gov/xcodf/1.1" exclude-result-prefixes="an">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="an:Banchmark">
<h2>My CD Collection</h2>
<h3><xsl:value-of select="an:status"/></h3>
<p><xsl:value-of select="an:version"/></p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform

And output is

<html>
   <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <h3>draft</h3>
      <p>0.6.3</p>
   </body>
</html>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

You failed to show what you have tried so far, but a far as HTML output is
concerned, you probably should include in your script `xsl:output` command,
specifying `method="html"`.

One of possible examples, e.g. to generate XHTML output is:

```
<xsl:output method="html"
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  doctype-system= "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"/>
```

You can give other values for both `doctype-...` attributes, according to your
needs.

Version attribute is usually not needed, but if for some reason you have to,
you can specify it with `version="..."` attribute in `xsl:output`.